# SSRS Expression Multiple IIF Lcase and replace

Tags: reporting-services, expression

I have the following expression :

```
=LCase(Replace(Fields!Column.Value,"ly",""))
```

which is fine for replacing the end of a word so Monthly would be Month, but I can't quite get the syntax right for if its `"ly"` OR `"LY"` .

Have tried `IIF` and `SWITCH` but my syntax is wrong somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use low case before the replace:

```
=Replace(LCASE(Fields!Column.Value),"ly","")
```

**UPDATE:** If you want to preserve the original case of the string you can use:

```
=REPLACE(REPLACE(Fields!Column.Value,"LY",""),"ly","")
```

Comment: I'm trying to do this =Replace(LCase(Fields!Column.Value,"ly" ,"")) OR Replace(LCase(Fields!Column.Value,"LY" ,"")) I can't figure out the syntax?

Comment: @SSMSJ, just use the expression I posted it will return `month` either for `MONTHLY` or `monthly`.